# How can app add on iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-update, app-distribution

One of my app is uploaded on mobile store, then after some months I have add new build but did not submit that build for review.
Now I updated my app with new designs and lots of changes. and I wanted to upload this new version on store. But I don’t know how to add app.

Because when I click on `iTunes Connect` --> `My Apps` --> `App Store` --> `+ VERSION OR PLATFORM`, it shows only tvOS and iOS is disabled.

So now, how can I remove app from Waiting for  Upload and how can I add new build ?

Here is screen shot :

[image: iTunes_connect]

I have read all documents provided by Apple Inc., but I didn’t found any option….related my scenario.

1. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html
2. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW34
3. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html
4. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html

If anyone knows, please let me know.

Thanks.

One more thing I forgot to tell that Also I want to update screenshots and description details.

Comment: You need to upload a binary for iOS and add it to the 1.4 version - as it says, it is waiting for upload.

Comment: But, I don't want to upload this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **creating a brand new version**, just **upload the binary, and then cancel it.** As I see you updated your question, this is a final solution for you then.

For uploading a build:

**1. Access the version page.**

Sou you should see a frame that will contain your build.

[image]

**2. Your binary should be uploaded** via

**a)** Xcode

**b)** Application loader

iTunes connect will pair your binary with the version according to the App ID and version saved in the Xcode target settings.

If you need to have the version of 2.0 for instance, change the version number both in

- **Xcode target build settings**
- within the **App version page**

[image]

Comment: But when I have uploaded app via Xcode, then it always add to TestFlight. So under `Activity` --> `All Builds` --> `iOS Builds` --> Version 1.5 --> Build 1.7. this is my latest version

Comment: That is correct. The you may need to select it from within the frame I posted in my answer. So you should select it and to see something like this: http://pasteboard.co/138FBBeia.png

Comment: Then also your version within the App version detail page should be set to 1.7 (or accordingly) - as in my answer - second screenshot (the little one).

Comment: but I also want to update screenshots. If I add new build, then how can I update screenshots ?

Comment: For creating brand new version, just upload the binary, and then cancel it. As I see you updated your question, this is a **final solution for you** then.

Comment: Means, at first I have to submit this version for review and then cancel it and upload new one ??

Comment: If you upload the binary, you can still freely cancel all the version as by uploading it is not actually going to the review, and the confirmation is needed.

Comment: No to submit, just upload and cancel. As you see, the iTunes Connect page is awaiting upload. So satisfy him. Then cancel it. Then create new version, as you wanted to do at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

First Try to upload it again.

If your upload is successful, it should be changed your status to Waiting For Review.

after change the status to waiting for uplaod -->> waiting for review and after that you an remove this app an add the new version and uplaod again.

follow this step:

step1- you can upload this build and change the status to waiting for review.

step2- after change the status you can delete this version.

step3- and create the new version and upload again with same screen shots.

To delete an app from the store and iTunes Connect

Open the App Details page for the app, as described in Creating an iTunes Connect Record for an App.
Make sure that the app status allows deletion.
You can delete your app if there is at least one approved version of the app and the latest version status is one of the following:

Prepare for Submission

Invalid Binary

Developer Rejected

Rejected

Metadata Rejected

Developer Removed From Sale

Removed from Sale

If your app has a different status, you can delete the app by first rejecting the build or by removing the app from sale. See Viewing and Changing Your App’s Status and Availability.

You can see more details at [Transferring And Deleting Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

Comment: I cannot see any `Delete` button

Answer (score 0):

Status for your Version 1.4 is waiting for upload. That means you must upload the App with Version 1.4 If you have already uploaded the app with version 1.4 and you don't want to use that build just increase the build number and keep the version number same 1.4.

[Image with Build Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHNri.png)

Comment: I don't want to upload this version. This version is added before one year. Now I have new one and want to add that one.

Comment: Which Version number you want to use for the new build ?

Comment: You will have to upload a binary for this version before you can create a new version. You don't need to submit version 1.4 for review